# Manual pause and resume functionality in AWS SWF java framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

Does SWF natively supports manual pause and resume workflow functionality in java framework? If not is there any way to achieve to achieve that semantics?

Edit: I implemented following example, seems to be working with initial testing. Is there anything which can break with this. My workflow is going to be long running (~3-5 hours) with same activity being multiple times with different params.

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Asynchronous;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.core.Promise;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.core.Settable;

public class GreeterWorkflowImpl implements GreeterWorkflow {
  private GreeterActivitiesClient operations = new GreeterActivitiesClientImpl();
  Settable<Void> paused = new Settable<>();
  public void greet() {
    Promise<String> fs = getGreeting(0, operations.getName());
    print(fs);
  }

  @Asynchronous
  private Promise<String> getGreeting(int count, Promise<String> name)
  {
    if (count > 10)
      return name;

    return getGreeting(count, name, paused);
  }

  @Asynchronous
  private Promise<String> getGreeting(int count, Promise<String> name, Settable<Void> paused) {

    Promise<String> returnString = operations.getGreeting(name.get());
    return getGreeting(count + 1, returnString);
  }

  @Asynchronous
  private void print(Promise<String> finalString)
  {
    System.out.println("Final String is " + finalString.get());
  }

  // @Signal method
  @Override
  public void pause() {
    paused = new Settable<>();
  }

  // @Signal method
  @Override
  public void resume() {
    paused.set(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks reasonable.

Comment: I was really hoping to get reply from you, thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

In case you get multiple signals for resume, you will be setting the paused settable again (which is already ready) so you might end up with unhandled IllegalStateException